# Function returning #VALUE error in expecting integer in VBA

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

I want a function that loops through closed workbooks having some parameters given from cells of another workbook. The aim is to count the number of presence of people in some locations considering a month. I'm getting `#VALUE` error when passing parameters in the sheet.

```
Option Explicit

Public Function count(collega As Range, luogo As Range, mese As Range) As Integer

Dim nomeMese As String
Dim nomeLuogo As String
Dim nomeCollega As String
Dim rangeLuogo As String
Dim stringaMese As String
Dim file As Variant
Dim wb As Workbook
'Dim count As Integer

count = 0
nomeMese = mese
nomeLuogo = luogo
nomeCollega = collega

Select Case True
    Case nomeLuogo = "ponte milvio"
        rangeLuogo = "$A$2:$B$2"
    Case Else
        rangeLuogo = "null"
End Select

Select Case True
    Case nomeMese = "Gennaio"
        stringaMese = "-01-2022"
    Case Else
        stringaMese = "null"
End Select
file = Dir("C:\Users\sbalo\Desktop\Test\*.xlsx") 'la funzione Dir permette di looppare senza specificare...

While (file <> "")
    If InStr(file, stringaMese) > 0 Then 'cerca nella directory il file con il match mese-anno
    Set wb = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\sbalo\Desktop\Test\" & file)
    count = count + Application.CountIf(wb.Sheets("Foglio1").Range(rangeLuogo), nomeCollega)
    wb.Close SaveChanges:=False
    End If
    file = Dir
Wend
End Function
```

Comment: Welcome! Please make sure the `wb` is open and contains a sheet named `Foglio1` before counting the `count` increment - COUNTIF() [**returns #VALUE! error**](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/countif-function-e0de10c6-f885-4e71-abb4-1f464816df34#:~:text=A%20COUNTIF%20formula%20receives%20a%20%23VALUE!%20error%20when%20referring%20to%20another%20worksheet.) in a specific case.

Comment: Hi, i've tested in vba console and seems to work correctly. When i'm calling function in the worksheet i'm getting value error..

Comment: I think this is implied, but try adding .value where you assign the range to strings e.g. `nomeLuogo = luogo.value`

Comment: unfortunately still having value error with luogo.value

Comment: also tried with .Value on  nomeCollega and nomeMese.

Comment: I've noticed that when testing in console i can see workbooks opening through their windows, but when calling function from a worksheet cell this does not happen.

Comment: Are you sure your "null" strings evaluate correctly? Note you are actually putting the letters "null" in the string and don't have a true null string. You might also be trying to access a named range called "null" which will through an error.

Comment: Worse case their might be a scope or security error in trying to access workbooks from function calls (maybe its not possible to wb.open from a function?). Do a simple test to see if you can return say cell A1 from a static external file via a UDF call. You might have to use a sub/macro.

Comment: I think that the problem is that i can't access another workbook from a Function. How can i implement this procedure with a Sub? I've tried to call sub from a new function but still having same problems.

Comment: I would put all the current arguments to the function in say columns A to C. Now call a macro with a commandbutton that loops throughs all the rows in A to C, open the files, does the count an store the answer D. In this way it is like column D is =count(A2,B2,C2) except D is static and must be refreshed manually by clicking the commandbutton.

Answer (score 1):

UDF in VBA are subject to certain restriction, like being unable to modify another cell, open workbooks etc.

Have a look here

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46782402/can-excel-vba-function-open-a-file

And here

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7693530/excel-vba-cant-open-workbook

The only workaround is to open another instance of Excel in the UDF, which can be a resource heavy exercise (see links). Make sure to close and quit all workbooks and that you dont call this UDF as part of a volatile function call that will recalculate all the time and slow down your workbook.

That, or rewrite your code to rather execute from a sub/macro linked to a button saying e.g. "refresh from external workbooks".

Comment: ok thank you guys, gave me a point of thinking

Comment: Kindly do checkmark the solution so others may know it has been solved.

Comment: thinked about it, not possible to add a button cause i need to change "dynamically" the nomeCollega (ColleagueName). Think it's possible only using "=function()" pattern

Comment: You can still change it dynamically. The macro just looks for its dynamic arguments in an extra help column. The only caveat is that the "answers" column that the macro updates, will not automatically update if you change the name in your helper column. You would need to hit the button after every change.

Comment: Ps. If you really need it to be automatic, you can also call the macro from within the Worksheet_change event so that the answers column updates whenever you edit a cell in the helper column range (the input arguments) (see https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office/troubleshoot/excel/run-macro-cells-change)